# How to refresh the website with Nancy if model data changed?

Tags: nancy

If my model data is changing how to refresh the site automatically to display the changed data?

Is this possible at the server or do I have to write some client code for this?

Thanks for helping.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write client side code to do this, the server has no relationship with the client once its sent the response - the connection is closed, the server moves on to other requests.

You need to use Javascript to poll the server and update based on server side changes - you can use a data binding framework such as Knock Out, or a larger framework such as Angular to make this easier.

SignalR may help you here, in that its a system which plugs into both the client and server side, keeps open a connection so you can send data to the client side instantly from the server.